Why does Jean Brodie renounce Teddy Lloyd, but encourage her students to sleep with him?
Here is part of a conversation that Sandy has with her former teacher Jean Brodie some years after the latter has been forced out of her teaching job:

      "Teddy Lloyd was greatly in love with me, as you know," said Miss Brodie, "and I with him. It was a great love. One day in the art room he kissed me. We never became lovers, not even after you left Edinburgh, when the temptation was strongest."
      Sandy stared through her little eyes at the hills.
      "But I renounced him," said Miss Brodie. "He was a married man. I renounced the great love of my prime."
Spark, Muriel. The Prime of Miss Jean Brodie. 1961. New York: HarperPerennial, 2009. p. 58. Accessed at archive.org 11 July 2024.

It's clear that Miss Brodie's love for the painter is reciprocated: one running joke in the novel is that no matter who sits for it, any portrait by Teddy Lloyd looks like a painting of Jean Brodie. And from this passage, it appears that despite their mutual passion, Miss Brodie does not enter into a sexual relationship with the painter because she wishes to respect his marriage. Instead, she has an affair with the unmarried Gordon Lowther, though she turns down his proposal because she does not return his love.
Yet she expects and even grooms her students to sleep with Lloyd:

      It was plain that Miss Brodie wanted Rose with her instinct to start preparing to be Teddy Lloyd's lover, and Sandy with her insight to act as informant on the affair. It was to this end that Rose and Sandy had been chosen as the crème de la crème. There was a whiff of sulphur about the idea which fascinated Sandy in her present mind. After all, it was only an idea. And there was no pressing hurry in the matter, for Miss Brodie liked to take her leisure over the unfolding of her plans, most of her joy deriving from the preparation, and moreover, even if these plans were as clear to her own mind as they were to Sandy's, the girls were too young. All the same, by the time they girls were sixteen, Miss Brodie was saying to her set at large: "Sandy will make an excellent Secret Service agent, a great spy"; and to Sandy alone she had started saying "Rose will be a great lover. She is above the common moral code, it does not apply to her. This is a fact which it is not expedient for anyone to hear about who is not endowed with insight."
      For over a year Sandy entered into the spirit of this plan, for she visited the Lloyds' frequently, and was able to report to Miss Brodie how things were going with the portraits of Rose which so resembled Miss Brodie.
      "Rose," said Miss Brodie, "is like a heroine from a novel by D. H. Lawrence. She has got instinct."
      But in fact the art master's interest in Rose was simply a professional one, she was a good model; Rose had an instinct to be satisfied with this role, and in the event it was Sandy who slept with Teddy Lloyd and Rose who carried back the information.
ibid., pp. 116–117.

Miss Brodie is well aware of, and even encourages, this affair:

She was at first merely resigned to Sandy's liaison with the art master. Presently she was exultant, and presently again enquired for details, which she did not get.
      "His portraits still resemble me?" said Miss Brodie.
      "Yes, very much," said Sandy.
      "Then all is well," said Miss Brodie. "And after all, Sandy," she said, "you are destined to be the great lover, although I would not have thought it. Truth is stranger than fiction. I wanted Rose for him, I admit, and sometimes I regret urging young Joyce Emily to go to Spain to fight for Franco, she would have done admirably for him."
ibid., pp. 132–133

I'm having trouble reconciling these various passages. Jean Brodie's own dalliance with Mr Lowther shows that she does not think of sex without marriage as inherently wrong. It could be possible that she nevertheless draws the line at adultery; however, this possibility is undercut by her statement that Rose is "above the common moral code" and her eventual delight in Sandy's fling. She neither rebukes Sandy nor condemns Mr Lloyd for their affair. Indeed, she makes a point of telling Sandy that even after Sandy had broken off matters and left Edinburgh, she herself never slept with him even though "the temptation was strongest" then.
What explains Miss Brodie's self-contradictory attitudes and behavior? How does her stated reason for forsaking Mr Lloyd, i.e., respect for his marriage, square with grooming Rose to sleep with him and with being "exultant" when Sandy does? And what actually stops her from sleeping with him?

"I regret urging young Joyce Emily to go to Spain to fight for Franco" - so Miss Jean Brodie was a fascist? I never knew that.

@ClaraDíazSanchez yep
